# How do I get bibtexU working?

Tags: bibtex, texlive, unicode

Running `bibtexu -v` (from TeX Live bundle) yields the message

```
This is BibTeXu: a UTF-8 Big BibTeX version 0.99d
Implementation:  Microsoft(R) C/C++ for Win32
Release version: 3.71 (18 mar 2013)
```

however I don't see any other manifestation that `bibtexu` could be really unicode-aware software. Moreover, when I run `bibtexu` on an `aux` file, it reports using 8-bit `csf` file:

```
The 8-bit codepage and sorting file: 88591lat.csf
```

and proceeds so slowly that I never could reach a finish. So my question: *What is `bibtexu` in fact?*

Comment: My experience is that `bibtexu` is undocumented, unsupported, buggy and really not to be recommended. I would strongly advise avoiding it: that's not really an answer!

Comment: If you want to know what it is, there's some information [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2010-May/025996.html).

Comment: Thank you, @JosephWright. This is also my opinion. Just, I was contacted by a user of my package `GOST` who wrote that it fails with `bibtexu`. By the way, `bibtexu` is excluded from MikTeX. Isn't worth to exclude it also from TL?

Comment: I think BibTeXU revived in TeX Live 2019 pretest. It seems that BibTeXu never worked since the beginning of TL integration (2010), but the first and the last "official" release by Yannis (in both sources and binaries format, 2009) worked; it could have been a failure in TL integration.

Answer (score 6):

The message about the `.csf` file is spurious. The documentation is scanty and the bugs are probably many. However, up to a certain extent it works.

I found a couple of Russian books with the help of Google books, that allows to export BibTeX data for the book.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
  title={О правѣ наказанія: Рѣчь, произнесенная в торжественном собраніи Демидовскаго лицея 29 ноября, 1859 года},
  author={Чебышев-Дмитриев, А.},
  url={http://books.google.it/books?id=uCYYAAAAYAAJ},
  year={1859},
  publisher={Фальк}
}
@book{b,
  title={Теорія сравненій},
  author={Чебышев, П.Л.},
  url={http://books.google.it/books?id=Sv7uAAAAMAAJ},
  year={1849},
  publisher={В тип. Императорской Академіи Наук}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[X2,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ѣ}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\char\string"78}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The yat must be defined because it isn't included in the T2A encoding. This is the `.bbl` file built by BibTeXU:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{b}
П.Л. Чебышев.
\newblock {\em Теорія сравненій}.
\newblock В тип. Императорской Академіи Наук,
  1849.

\bibitem{a}
А. Чебышев-Дмитриев.
\newblock {\em О правѣ наказанія: Рѣчь,
  произнесенная в торжественном собраніи
  Демидовскаго лицея 29 ноября, 1859 года}.
\newblock Фальк, 1859.

\end{thebibliography}
```

[image]

Can I recommend it? No, of course. Use `biblatex` if you can.

There is a thread on the TeX Live list, started with [this message by Joseph Wright](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2010-May/025973.html); here's the answer by Karl Berry:

> No, it is an independent project.  bibtex8 still exists (and is still in
>   TL).  In fact, Peter put in yeoman efforts to update bibtex, bibtex8,
>   bibtexu so that they had more or less the same behavior wrt memory
>   allocation, etc.
>
> bibtexu is/was a project by Yannis (and a student or two) to use the ICU
>   library with BibTeX.  Peter also put in the massive efforts needed to
>   make this work in the TL build system and have bibtexu and xetex use the
>   same ICU library
>
> I have never seen any documentation or other details about bibtexu.  I
>   asked Yannis about it a couple days ago; no response as of yet.

I believe it's a dead project, unfortunately.

Comment: On my comp (Win7, TL 2013) bibtexu hangs. I've never seen it finished.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov I know nothing about Win, sorry.